# How to center the xticks from a bar chart

Tags: python, matplotlib, bar-chart, xticks

I was following this tutorial to add value in my bar chart [link](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/adding-value-labels-on-a-matplotlib-bar-chart)

The code that shown in the blog written like this

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

years = [1901, 1911, 1921, 1931, 1941, 1951, 1961, 1971, 1981, 1991, 2001, 2011]
population = [237.4, 238.4, 252.09, 251.31, 278.98, 318.66, 361.09, 439.23, 548.16, 683.33, 846.42, 1028.74]

x = np.arange(len(years)) # the label locations
width = 0.35 # the width of the bars

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.set_ylabel('Population(in million)')
ax.set_title('Years')
ax.set_xticks(x)
ax.set_xticklabels(years)

pps = ax.bar(x - width/2, population, width, label='population')
for p in pps:
   height = p.get_height()
   ax.annotate('{}'.format(height),
      xy=(p.get_x() + p.get_width() / 2, height),
      xytext=(0, 3), # 3 points vertical offset
      textcoords="offset points",
      ha='center', va='bottom')

plt.show()
```

So, the output become like this

[image]

But, I just realized that the xticks from the bar chart is not centered

[image]

My question - Is anybody know how to center the xticks?

I was trying to find the solution, but not found yet

Comment: Just `pps = ax.bar(x, population, width, label='population')` without offsetting x?

Comment: well yeah, thanks again @HenryEcker

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `matplotlib` 3.4.0 or newer [`bar_label`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.bar_label.html#matplotlib-axes-axes-bar-label) can be used instead of [`annotate`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.annotate.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.annotate):

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

years = [1901, 1911, 1921, 1931, 1941, 1951, 1961, 1971, 1981, 1991, 2001, 2011]
population = [237.4, 238.4, 252.09, 251.31, 278.98, 318.66, 361.09, 439.23,
              548.16, 683.33, 846.42, 1028.74]

# Create Tick Locations
x = np.arange(len(years))
# Plotting
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 6))
# Do not offset the values of x to center labels (default)
ax.bar(x, population, width=.35, label='population')

# Labels, ticks, etc.
ax.set_ylabel('Population(in million)')
ax.set_title('Years')
ax.set_xticks(x)
ax.set_xticklabels(years)

# Add Bar Labels
for c in ax.containers:
    ax.bar_label(c)

plt.show()
```

[image: plot]

Comment: Now I gotta go check out the what's new of `matplotlib` thanks for sharing! Seems like you may be able to use `bar_container = ax.bar(...); ax.bar_label(bar_container)` instead of fetching the bar_container from the Axes object. But awesome to know about this nonetheless!!

Comment: Yes There's only one container in this example. But if you have multiple containers  (stacked bar plots for example) you'll need to iterate. I like to do the iterative approach so that it (almost) always works.

Answer (score 1):

imo that tutorial is making plotting more confusing than it needs to be. You seldom need to fetch coordinates from the artists on the plot. Just use your data directly:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

years = [1901, 1911, 1921, 1931, 1941, 1951, 1961, 1971, 1981, 1991, 2001, 2011]
population = [237.4, 238.4, 252.09, 251.31, 278.98, 318.66, 361.09, 439.23, 548.16, 683.33, 846.42, 1028.74]

x_values = np.arange(len(years))
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 4))

ax.bar(x_values, population, width=.35, label='population')
for x, y in zip(x_values, population):    
    ax.annotate(
        str(y),        # label is our y-value as a string
        xy=(x, y),
        xytext=(0, 3), # 3 points vertical offset
        textcoords="offset points",
        ha='center', 
        va='bottom'
    )
    
    
ax.set_xticks(x_values)
ax.set_xticklabels(years)
ax.set_ylim(0, 1200)

plt.show()
```

[image]